# how to use shape in ListTileTheme?

Tags: flutter, listview, border, shapes

```
ListTileTheme(

          shape: ??? ,

          tileColor: MyTheme.redColor,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
          child: ExpansionTile()
        )
```

I Need to make a border-radius , how can I do this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You can use a widget such as [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) to create a border radius.

Example:

```dart
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
      ),
      child: ListTile(),
    );
```

If you want to use the `shape` parameter in `ListTileTheme`, you can use `RoundedRectangleBorder` like this:

```dart
return ListTileTheme(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
  ),
  child: ListTile(),
),
```

Comment: the second one not working, but the first one is working. Thank you @Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: MyTheme.redColor,
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
 ),
 child: ListTile(),
)
```

Approach 2:

```
ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
   child: Container(
     color: MyTheme.redColor,
     child: ListTile(),
   ),
)
```

Approach 3:

```
ListTileTheme(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
   ),
   child: ListTile(
     tileColor: MyTheme.redColor, 
   ),
)
```

Preferred: Approach 2